# IBM T60 ThinkPad mouse pad malfunction

Tags: windows, drivers, touchpad

I had to recently buy a new computer. I have had it for seven days.

The mouse pad is not functioning. I have installed all UltraNav drivers, and other software From Lenovo as well as the IBM site. It continues saying:

> system device not found

Comment: What are "unav drivers"?

Comment: @slhck they are for the funky [UltraNav thang](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/UltraNav) that thinkpads have.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that this is a 7 day old laptop, your first inclination should be to return it for a replacement. A unit this young and with presumably a full warrantee, you should not have to spend time in a “fix” while you have the ability to return and replace.

Answer (score 1):

As the T60 is similar to my T61, I think there may be a base system driver need as well.  Is tehr any hardware item in Device Manager with an Exclamation point?

If using the ThinkVanage driver update tool does not resolve an exclamation point, try the [Unknown Device Identifier](http://www.zhangduo.com/udi.html)

Also, given the age of the T60, is it possible the touchpad has failed?  Or is this not a T60 from about 2006ish?